# NonEnglish chars/parameters to function with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

For example I have this address:

> http://www.domain.com/page/**page-name**

`page-name` is always changed, by the name of the page.

In addition, the `page-name` is not written with English chars.

My function is for example:

```
function index($name)
{
    echo $name;
}
```

But then the name is converted to something like `%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%992` and of course it's not the name which I except to get.

The encoding of the page is UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode) the string.

```
$name = urldecode($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->uri->segment(n)`.

For more information about it refer [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) link. This will definitely help you returning any url segment.